# executePhantomJS on Remotewebdriver

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, remotewebdriver

if I use a web driver then it works perfectly

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
driver.executePhantomJS( "var page = this;");
```

How can I make it work?

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
driver.executePhantomJS( "var page = this;");
```

UPDATE

My code

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);


driver.executePhantomJS( "var page = this; binary =0;mimetype=''; count = 0;id=0; bla = '{';"
                                +"page.onResourceReceived = function(request) {"
                                    + "if(id !== request.id){"
                                        +"bla += '\"'+count+ '\":'+JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4)+',';"
                                        +"if(request.contentType.substring(0, 11) =='application'){"
                                            +"console.log(request.contentType);"
                                            + "mimetype = request.contentType;"
                                            + "binary++;"
                                        + "}"
                                        +"count++;"
                                        + "id = request.id;"
                                    + "}"                       
                                +"};");
```

Java gives error: The method executePhantomJS(String) is undefined for the type RemoteWebDriver.

If i use executeScript it will not work.

I need run 100 test parallel, i can't use webdriver.

Comment: I want to 100 test run parallel

Comment: if I run 100 tests at the same time then crashes my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you wanna run PhantomJSDriver on your Se Grid. This is how it works for me (C# Factory implementation):

```
public IWebDriver CreateWebDriver(string identifier)
    {
     if (identifier.ToLower().Contains("ghostdriver"))
        {
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Selenium.grid.Url"]), DesiredCapabilities.PhantomJS());
        }
    }
```

or try this one

```
   Console.WriteLine("Creating GhostDriver (PhantomJS) driver.");
   //Temporary commented for testing purposes
   IWebDriver ghostDriver = new PhantomJSDriver("..\\..\\..\\MyFramework\\Drivers");
                ghostDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                //ghostDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
                ghostDriver.Manage()
                    .Timeouts()
                    .SetPageLoadTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0,
                        Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Driver.page.load.time.sec"])));
                return ghostDriver;
```

In case that you wonder why there is `ConfigurationManager` - I avoid the hard-coded values, so they are extracted from the `App.config` file.

Comment: I have a connection PhantomJSDriver+Selenium Grid.

Comment: I want to execute phantomjs script on Selenium grid

Comment: The code I gave you is the solution. And just FYI - the drivers doesn't care what 'scripts' will be passed to them regarding the browser (Firefox, Chrome, Phantom, IE etc.).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, because OP is not using C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run PhantomJS scripts with RemoteWebDriver (for using the Selenium Grid), I used the following solution (only C# unfortunately):

1. I had to extend the RemoteWebDriver so it can run PhantomJS commands:

   ```
   public class RemotePhantomJsDriver : RemoteWebDriver
   {
       public RemotePhantomJsDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) : base(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilities)
       {
           this.CommandExecutor.CommandInfoRepository.TryAddCommand("executePhantomScript", new CommandInfo("POST", $"/session/{this.SessionId.ToString()}/phantom/execute"));
       }

       public Response ExecutePhantomJSScript(string script, params object[] args)
       {
           return base.Execute("executePhantomScript", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "script", script }, { "args", args } });
       }
   }
   ```
2. After this you can use the ExecutePhantomJSScript method to run any JavaScript code that wants to interact with the PhantomJS API. The following example gets the page title trough the PhantomJS API (Web Page Module):

   ```
   RemotePhantomJsDriver driver = new RemotePhantomJsDriver(new Uri("http://hub_host:hub_port/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.PhantomJS());
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
   var result = driver.ExecutePhantomJSScript("var page = this; return page.title");
   Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
   driver.Quit();
   ```

Comment: I realize this goes back some time, but I've just tried this on Selenium 3.0.1 and it does not seem to work.  The command appears to be successfully added, but at runtime I get this when firing a script:

```
System.NotImplementedException : POST /session/xxxx/phantom/execute
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: I've just tried the above code, and worked OK, I've used the following tools: 
1. C# NET Core Console application with CoreCompat.Selenium.WebDriver package version 3.2.0-beta003
2. I've used the docker containers from here: [link]https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium (the selenium/hub and selenium/node-phantomjs container images with the newest versions)